# I cannot open Ubuntu Software Center on 17.04 in the normal way or using the command line

Tags: software-center

This is a screenshot of `gnome-center`

[image]

I can see that the Software Center is installed, I can find it in Unity as well. But when I click on it, it doesn't seem to want to open. So, I tried the command line method, but that is not working either.

I cannot seem to open the Ubuntu Software Center by either the normal way or by using the command line `software-center`, which results in `command not found`.

What am I getting wrong here and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The old Ubuntu Software Center `software-center` is not included in 17.04. The creators intended for you to use `gnome-software` instead.

Comment: Yes, I tried that too! It would just sit there looking all pretty but won't do a thing! Would I always have to type in a command line just to pop open a software center?

Comment: Did you upgrade to 17.04, or do a clean install?

Comment: I upgraded from the previous version. If I remember correctly, software center used to open but only after several attempts and after a very long time. This has only been happening with 17.04 though.

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with the upgrade process.

Comment: @shikhars did you clean up the GNOME software caches in your home directory?

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto No, I did not. Can you tell me the right way to do it and what should happen once I do it? I'll try to do it now and if that does not work or if I do not see whatever it is that is supposed to happen next, I'll do a clean installation of the entire OS. I've a complete backup.